# Capistrano laravel htaccess redirect to subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

so I have the following problem:

I have a webspace and one url `www.domain.com` points to the root folder.

I want any request to `www.domain.com/app/` to be rewritten to the folder `/apps/app/current/public/` (it is a laravel app deployed via capistrano).

However the url should stay as it was, so e.g. `www.domain.com/app/user-page` would be rewritten to `/apps/app/current/public/user-page`.

How can I do this with htaccess?

What I currently have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /apps/app/current/public/index.php?/$1 [NC,L]
```

---

But obviously this only works at domain.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ /apps/app/current/public/index.php?/$1 [NC,L]
```

leads to my app receiving app and whatever is after it as the url, howerver, it should only receive whatever is after the `app/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, to than notice, that this does not work with laravel, because the `/app` part is still in the url.

So as far as I know it does not work.